# Functions and 'Function' constructor

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

First of all, I am not asking about the difference between creating functions with function definitions (or expressions) and using the 'Function' constructor....
I know that the three of them are used in creating functions with specific differences that I already know.

What I am trying to say is that functions - as known in javascript -  are first-class objects and any function is an instance of the 'Function' constructor.

My question is what is the point in javascript that makes having a constructor function especially for functions essential?

Philosophically speaking, if 'Function' constructor - which is a function - is the constructor of functions so what is the constructor of the constructor function 'Function'?

It may be a strange question but it's really confusing!

Comment: `Function.constructor === Function`

Comment: Re "*…what is the constructor of the constructor function 'Function'*", there doesn't need to be one, it's a built-in object that exists when a global execution context is created.

Comment: @RobG Can you link your facebook account here, please?

Comment: Not all function objects are created by calling `new Function`. Philosophically speaking: what was there first, the chicken or the egg? The function or the prototype object?

Comment: @YousefEssam—what Facebook account?

Answer (score -1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript every function is actually a Function object.

The important part is that all functions are actually Function objects.

Function objects are useful for parsing strings as functions without the use of eval. They are useful for dynamically creating functions whose parameters and function body may not be known at compile time.

Comment: *"Function objects are useful for parsing strings as functions without the use of eval."* - Do you mean that the `Function()` function is useful for that? You already said "all functions are actually Function objects", but not all functions parse strings, so...

Comment: The Function() constructor is useful for that. If you want to load functions from a file or a database you can do that: `var f = new Function('x', "return x+2")` and then call the function: `f(2)`.

Comment: Yes, I know what `Function()` does. I'm saying that the sentence I quoted in italics is incorrect, and it disagrees with the sentence before it.